# Where did Buddha state "Mother is the Buddha of the home?"

Tags: reference-request, tipitaka

I grew up in Sri Lanka where we often hear

> Gedara budun amma

Which translates to

> Buddha of the house is mother

I also learned that this was to reinstate the lost value of a mother in the country back then due to discrimination of women.

I'm positive there are proper references for this but I would like to know where in Tipitaka or other historical books this is documented.

Comment: So far I've not come across this in the scriptures, but I'm very interested to find out as to how ths came to be. Even  **[THIS](http://mahamegha.lk/2015/12/31/mahabowai-mata-maye-amma/)** article dedicated to the mother makes no mention of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only aware of the suttas stating:

> *Mother and father are called
>   "Brahma," "early teachers"
>   And "worthy of veneration,"
>   Being compassionate towards
>   Their family of children.*
>
> [*Iti 109*](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/iti/iti.4.106-112x.irel.html)
>
> ---
>
> *A wife as the West be ministered to by a husband by...handing over authority to her...*
>
> [*DN 31*](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html)
>
> ---

DN 31 also states:

> *(iv) she protects what he brings, (v) she is skilled and industrious in discharging her duties.*
>
> ---

The wife has authority in the home when she is financially prudent, like my mother. But many women of the current 'feminist sexual liberal era' lack financial prudence. Instead of saving money, they spend money. Only individuals with morality can be the authority of the home.

Comment: I believe this was the case, which later got interpreted differently.

Answer (score 1):

"Mother is the Buddha of the home", might also refer to the Mother as the first source from which to learn selfless, compassionate love.

http://www.dailymirror.lk/109260/Mother-the-Buddha-at-home-Gedara-Budun-